# Closing Wordpress database connections to reduce CPU usage

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cpu, cpu-usage

I’ve been having CPU usage that goes way over with my PHP scripts running.

Every PHP script opens a connection to MySQL using the [`wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) file from Wordpress. I know that Wordpress’ connection closes automatically at the end of each page, but I’m using the `include` or `require_once` for the `wp-config.php` file which opens the connection to insert data into other tables that I’ve created on my own. My script runs and checks if there are > 0 rows (`mysql_num_rows`). If there are, then it continues to run, if not then I put in `exit;` to stop it from running to save resources.

Do I need to close these connections somehow or are they closing by themselves anyway? If I do need to close them, how?

I just see some high CPU usage when multiple PHP scripts run and could use someone’s advice on this. Maybe there’s nothing wrong and I just need to upgrade my server. I have a quad core server with 4 GB of RAM. Memory usage never goes above 40 % and CPU usage can go as high as 200 % which I’ve seen because PHP scripts end up spawning due to high CPU usage making things go slow. Web traffic is next to none!

Comment: No, php closes connections to mysql when the script ends. Your high CPU will probably come from somewhere else. You can narrow it down with top, htop, atop, and iotop on the command line.

Comment: The times when I see mysql go high is when a whole bunch of PHP scripts start running. We have about 1000 PHP scripts that run on a schedule. I'm using w3 total cache plugin as well, but disabled it because I think that it was taking up resources as well. Our sites (36) update every 5 minutes or so with new posts using XML-RPC so didn't see a real point in caching. Maybe I'm wrong? I've been using top as well on the command line. Your other variations of top do not work in my SSH

Comment: You should go the other direction and try persistent db connections. Plus caching would avoid unnecessary queries.